# Using reduce to get the total amount of payment in React ecommerce basket

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to calculate the total price of a shopping cart by using a selector/ getBasketTotal function in the reducer. this is the function:

```
export const initialState = {
  basket: []
};

export const getBasketTotal = basket =>
  basket.reduce((amount, item) => item.price + amount, 0);
```

This is how I am going to display the total amount in the webpage:

```
const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  return (
    <div className="subtotal">
      <CurrencyFormat
        renderText={value => (
          <>
            <p>
              Subtotal ({basket.length} items): <strong>{value}</strong>
            </p>
            <small className="subtotal__gift">
              <input type="checkbox" />
              This order contains a gift
            </small>
          </>
        )}
        decimalScale={2}
        value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
        displayType={"text"}
      />
```

The value will be displaying the total amount by calling the function getBasketTotal with a basket as the parameter.

The problem occurred was that the total amount was displayed as the price of the recently added items instead of the total sum of the items in the basket. Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Your `getBasketTotal` function looks to be correct, though I need to ask if all items have a `price` property that is of type number. Do you have an example set of basket state for to test your implementation with?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `react-hooks`.

In your case, `useMemo()` looks proper.

```js
const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

const getBasketTotal = React.useMemo(() => {
  return basket.reduce((amount, item) => item.price + amount, 0);
}, [basket]);

return { .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your reduce function is wrong. If it's a object like { price: 4 }, you should return an object with price key.

```
basket.reduce((amount, item) => ({ price: item.price + amount.price }));
```

Alternative you perform a map **before** a reduce to extract the price.

```
basket.map(x => x.price).reduce((amount, item) => amount+item);
```

**Example Snippet**

```js
const prices = [
    { price: 3 },
    { price: 4 },
    { price: 5 }
]



console.log('Correct Reduce', prices.reduce((a, b) => ({ price: a.price + b.price })))


console.log('Map before Reduce', prices.map(x => x.price).reduce((a,b) => a+b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your price variables.
These must be declared as a number not as a String

Comment: Please remove the "I had the same problem", as it's not relevant for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to conver sting from basket array into number type to get totalprice amount.

```
export const getBasketTotal = (basket) => {
    return basket?.reduce((amount, item) => Number(item.price) + amount, 0);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Your price in basket state should be:
price={9999999}

Probably added:
price="9999999"